# Trouble with passing ID with <Link> - Should i still use useRouter?

Tags: next.js, routes

I'm having trouble understanding how to use useRouter in the new app router. I want to ensure that my application runs on the client side. Specifically, when a user clicks on the href to post.id, I need to route the post.id to the next component.

Here's the structure of my parent component:

```js
<ul className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-3">
  {posts.map((post) => (
    <li key={post.id}>
      <Link href={`/${props.params.workspaceId}/${post.id}`}>
        <Card className="overflow-hidden">
          <div
            className="h-32"
            style={getRandomPatternStyle(post.id.toString())}
          />
          <CardHeader>
            <CardTitle className="flex items-center justify-between">
              <span>{post.title}</span>
              <ProjectTierIndicator tier={ProjectTier.FREE} />
            </CardTitle>
            <CardDescription>{post.url}&nbsp;</CardDescription>
          </CardHeader>
        </Card>
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

The code above represents the part where the href goes. However, the code is not currently working, and I'm trying to figure out why.

In the next component, which is the Page component, I have the following code:

```js
export default function Page(props: { params: { workspaceId: string } }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  const post = prisma.post.findUnique({
    where: { id: Number(id) },
  });

  return (
    <DashboardShell
      title="Address Name in here"
      description="Projects for this workspace will show up here"
      headerAction={<SaveEditorButton />}
    >
      <Editor />
    </DashboardShell>
  );
}
```

I'm using useRouter from Next.js to get the id from the query string. However, it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Is there another way of doing this in the new app router nextjs13?

Could you please help me understand how I can properly use useRouter to route the post.id to the next component? I want to ensure that this routing operation runs on the client side.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!